# I need to get id from HTML using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

This is my code:

```
$('.image1').click(function(){ 
    $('.loader').show();
    function preloadImages(images, callback) {
        var count = images.length;  
        var loaded = 0;
        $(images).each(function() {
            $('<img>').attr('src', this).load(function() {
                loaded++;
                if (loaded === count) {
                    callback();
                }
            });
        });
    }; 

    preloadImages(["../images/Wedding_p/large/1.jpg",                                      
           "../images/Wedding_p/large/2.jpg",
           "../images/Wedding_p/large/3.jpg", 
           "../images/Wedding_p/large/4.jpg",
           "../images/Wedding_p/large/5.jpg"],    function() {
               alert("DONE");
               // In here I need to get id of '.image1' image.
           }
```

this is html:

```
<div>
    <img src = '1.jpg' data-id='1' class = 'image1'>
    <img src = '2.jpg' data-id='2' class = 'image1'> 
    <img src = '3.jpg' data-id='3' class = 'image1'>
</div>
```

When I click on the image I need the data-id of clicked image; how can I get it using my jQuery code.

Comment: Use $(this).attr('data-id');

Comment: i try it but the alert say undefined.. plz give me another option.

Comment: Store $(this) to a variable 

    $('.image1').click(function(){
    var _this = $(this);
And then 

    alert("DONE");
    alert(_this.attr('data-id'));

Comment: I think your `preloadImages` function doesn't `callback` properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.image1', function() {
   alert($(this).data("id"));
});
```

Comment: try  alert($(this).attr("data-id"));

Comment: thank u for answer my question.. plz give me  another option.

Comment: i try it .. when i click on it it say undefined

Comment: in click event use '.image1' instead of 'img'..i have updated code above

Answer (score 4):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("img").click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('data-id')); 
 });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
     <img src = '1.jpg' data-id='1' class = 'image1'>
         <img src = '2.jpg' data-id='2' class = 'image1'> 
         <img src = '3.jpg' data-id='3' class = 'image1'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to get the value of data-id attribute

```
$(this).attr('data-id');
```

Comment: jQuery already has a function to access data attributes https://api.jquery.com/data/